# LibGdx Camera starts from mid screen

Tags: android, libgdx

I am using LibGdx for my game development. I am new to this.
I have setup my camera like

```
public void create() { 
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(game.SCREEN_WIDTH, game.SCREEN_HEIGHT);
}
```

I am drawing the background like i have shown below.

```
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) { 
    sb.draw(BACKGROUND, 0, 0,1080,1920);
    sb.draw(BACKGROUND,0,1920,1080,1920);
    sb.draw(BACKGROUND,0,3840,1080,1920); 
}
```

With this setup I am getting the screen with the image starts from width/2,height/2 Instead of (0,0). Please let me know where my code needs correction.

Comment: I just added 
  camera.setToOrtho(false, game.SCREEN_WIDTH, game.SCREEN_HEIGHT); It is fine now

Comment: Camera is by default centered on (0, 0). If you draw your background starting at (0, 0) (bottom left corner of the texture), it will appear to start in the middle of your screen.